# How to determine maximum angles between vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm attempting to distribute vectors with the same origin with a maximum angle of separation.  Then if given a set of vectors, I want to determine how far from maximum separation they are.  For instance in 2D, two vectors would be 180 degrees apart, 3 would be 120, 4 90, etc.  So my two problems are determining maximum separation in 3D and giving some sort of feedback on how close they are to maximum separation.

Thanks

Comment: see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem

Comment: Much appreciated!  I think I can get close enough to what I want by just using the 12 vertices of an icosahedron.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening very deep problems about sphere packings, kissing numbers and so on here.
A very rough estimate would be the following:
The curved surface of a [sperical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) on the unit ball with angle $\alpha$ is $2\pi(1-\cos\alpha)$. Hence if you have $n$ vectors and all angles between them are $\ge2\alpha$, then we can compare areas and find $2n\pi(1-\cos\alpha)\le 4\pi$, i.e. the number
$$ \frac{n(1-\cos\alpha)}2$$
can be taken as a simple estimation for the "quality": The closer the value is to $1$, the better. Note however, that $1$ cannot be reached (except for $n=2$) and in fact for $n\to \infty$, we cannot beat the hexagonal density $\frac\pi{\sqrt{12}}\approx0.9$.