# Maximum equal angle separation between $n$ (unit) vectors in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Consider $n$ unit vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space. Assume that the angle between any pair of two vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$ is the same. Then, what would be the maximum for this angle?

I think the solution is quite easy for the $d>n$ case since in this case the vectors form a simplex.

I am curious for the solutions in the general case of $n>d$.

I found some posts ([link1][1][link2][2][link3][3]) that discuss a similar problem, but couldn't really find a solution to this.

Also, the [paper][4] here seems to calculate the estimated value for the maximum angle; namely,Eq. (7) in the appendix of the paper
$$
A \approx n^{-\frac{2}{d-1}} \Gamma(1 + \frac{1}{d-1}) 
\left( 
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}{2 \sqrt{\pi} (d-1) \Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})}
\right)^{-\frac{1}{d-1}}.
$$
I am wondering if this estimation is actually correct (the paper lacks the derivation of this approximation).

Using Wolfram, I computed the value for $n=10^4$ with $d=512$, obtaining $A \approx 0.94$. Would this make sense?

[1]: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778459/maximum-angle-of-separation-between-n-vectors-in-m-dimensions#:~:text=In%202D%20Given%202,simply%20divide%20360%20by%20n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778459/maximum-angle-of-separation-between-n-vectors-in-m-dimensions#:%7E:text=In%202D%20Given%202,simply%20divide%20360%20by%20n)).
[2]: [How to determine maximum angles between vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297209/how-to-determine-maximum-angles-between-vectors)
[3]: [Is this really an open problem? Maximizing angle between $n$ vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663014/is-this-really-an-open-problem-maximizing-angle-between-n-vectors?rq=1)
[4]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07698

Comment: It's not possible in the general case. For example, there's no way to have four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the angle between any two is the same. [A002853](http://oeis.org/A002853) might be useful.